# Geocoding Service: Exceeded daily request quota for API

Tags: google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoding-api

HTML

```
<div class="google-map">
    <div class="map" id="map" data-address="Gatterholzgasse 14, 1120 Wien"> 
</div>
```

JS

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initMap);

function initMap() {

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var $maps = $('.map');

    if($maps.length) {
        $maps.each(function() {
            var map = this;
            var $map = $(this);
            var address = $map.data('address');
            var latLng, gMap, pin;

            geocoder.geocode({ 'address' : address }, function(results, status) {
                if( status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK ) {
                    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                } else {
                    console.log("Geocoding unsuccessful. Reason: " + status);

                    latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(48.1792339,16.3194208,17);
                }

                var styledMap = new google.maps.StyledMapType(mapStyle, { name: 'Styled Map' });

                gMap = new google.maps.Map(map, {
                    center: latLng,
                    zoom: 17,
                    disableDefaultUI: true,
                    scrollwheel: true
                });

                gMap.mapTypes.set('map_style', styledMap);
                gMap.setMapTypeId('map_style');

                pin = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: latLng,
                    map: gMap,
                    icon: './img/google-map/map-pin.png',
                    title: 'Gatterholzgasse 14, 1120 Wien'
                });
            });
        });
    }
}
```

Google chrome console error

```
Geocoding Service: You have exceeded your daily request quota for this API.  For more information on usage limits and the Google Maps JavaScript API services please see: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/usage
Geocoding unsuccessful. Reason: OVER_QUERY_LIMIT
You have exceeded your request quota for this API. See https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/error-messages?utm_source=maps_js&utm_medium=degraded&utm_campaign=billing#api-key-and-billing-errors
```

[image]

I tried to change API key, but nothing has changed.

I read that the daily free limit is 25000 unique visitors, but I definitely does not have.

Any suggestion will be appreciate. Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you include a key with your requests for the API?  Have you added a billing to your account?  Please see: https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/

Comment: @geocodezip thank you for your answer, yes I included a api key , but I dont added a billing method to my account? Is that necessary to add billing method because I dont need to pay ?

Comment: from [the link in my first comment](https://cloud.google.com/maps-platform/user-guide/): As of June 11, 2018, you must enable billing with a credit card and have a valid API key for all of your projects.